# Parsing a string to a pointer array of chars: char[0] contains the full string and [1] onward contains nothing

Tags: c++, string, parsing, pointers, char

I'm trying to parse a simple string to an array of *char and for some reason when I use string.c_str() it puts the entire string into *char[0] and the rest of the array is left blank (I originally thought that chars could only hold one ASCII character but I guess that they act differently as pointers), could anyone have a scan through my function and tell me if there are any obvious mistakes?

```
static void SetGame()
{
    // Variable Initiation
    int myRandom = rand() % (numOfWords - 1);
    lengthOfString = wordArray[myRandom].length();

    // Reinitiate Pointer Arrays
    stringArray = new string[lengthOfString];
    isDiscoveredArray = new bool[lengthOfString];

    // Parse string to the array of characters
    *stringArray = wordArray[myRandom].c_str();

    // Set each boolean array value to false
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(isDiscoveredArray); i++)
    {
        isDiscoveredArray[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Here are my decelerations of the pointers

```
// Global Variable and pointer Declerations
string *wordArray;
int numOfWords;
string *stringArray;
int lengthOfString;
bool *isDiscoveredArray;
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have an array of `char` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Opps, stringArray is supposed to be charArray :P

Comment: Global variables are incredibly bad, and so is `new[]`. And why the hell would you use `*wordArray[myRandom].c_str()`? There's absolutely no need for the `c_str()` call.

Comment: Unless you're programming a system on a chip with less than 32Kb of RAM a couple of global variables here and there aren't that bad and string.c_str() was the simplest way for me to parse a string to an array of chars, if you had read the answer and some comments then you would have known that me declaring it as a string was the mistake that was causing my problem, thanks for the input though!

Comment: Memory has jack shit to do with why global variables are one of the worst ideas in programming. In fact, they are even *worse* when dealing with larger systems- much, much worse.

Comment: Could you elaborate for me please? And also for this assignment our Lecturer has told me to not use Classes which makes it very difficult to keep track of variables being input and output from functions. (The reason for it was that in our first term of uni they teach us programming as though we've never even heard of C so he wants to be able to mark us all on level grounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing types here. First you build an array of strings and store it in a pointer, then you assign to the first element a `const char*` coming from c_str. The code you currently have would be if your were creating a `string` for every character in your selected word.

Make your "stringArray" a `const char*` to fit with the code you already have, but **remove the memory allocation**.

Comment: I face palmed pretty damned hard when I saw that, changed it and it now works perfectly now, thanks! But damn, I've made a few mistakes and typos in my code but that one was just plain embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

You've got an array of std::string and when you deference it (i.e. *stringArray) its the same as stringArray[0], so that is why it always going into the first element of your array.

Since you are setting your array have the same number of elements as the string your are copying has characters, you may just want to use a string rather than a string array to copy it into.

If it supposed to be char* (character array) then you will need to explicitly copy the source, which is the result of wordArray[myRandom].c_str(), into your character array rather than using simple assignment.